# Non-Homogenous 2nd ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation: $2y''+3y'+y=(x+2)e^{-x}$

I am wondering how you could go about dealing with this forcing term when they are multiplied.

I understand if it was: $(x+2) + e^{-x}$ but that isn't the case! Thanks.

Comment: Have you learned the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: Yep, just not when the forcing term is multiplied.

Comment: Well then, the undetermined coefficients method is all about guessing solutions. If the forcing term was $(x+2)$, you'd guess $Ax+B$. If it was $e^{-x}$, you'd guess $Cxe^{-x}$ since $Ce^{-x}$ is already in the homogeneous solution. Take $(Ax+B)(xe^{-x})$ as a guess and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

$$2y′′+3y′+y=(x+2)e^{−x}$$
$$2(y′′+y')+(y′+y)=(x+2)e^{−x}$$
$$2(e^xy′′+e^xy')+(e^xy′+ye^x)=(x+2)$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$2(e^xy')'+(e^xy)'=(x+2)$$
$$(2e^xy'+e^xy)'=x+2$$
$$(2(e^xy)'-e^xy)'=x+2$$
$$(2u'-u)'=x+2$$
With $u=e^xy$. And integrate.

Comment: Always simple and efficient ! I am not speaking about the result itself. Cheers :-)

Comment: Oh thank you Claude @ClaudeLeibovici